# Is there already a way to generate an xsd:ID value in java?

Tags: java, xml

In xml, there are ID IDREF and IDREFS types built in to the spec. IDREF and IDREFS are supposed to tie directly to ID values and schema validation should fail if every IDREF value does not have a corresponding ID value.

Before I roll my own, I was wondering if java (or apache) has something already created for creating ID values that adhere to the ID format. If you are unfamiliar with the spec ID values must adhere to the same rules xml tag names do:

```
[4]     NameStartChar      ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
[4a]    NameChar           ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
[5]     Name               ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
```

Generating a UUID almost gets us there, but uuids that start with a numeric would cause a problem. Obviously a simple implementation would be prefixing a guid with any of the NameStartChar values. In the spirit of standardizing, is there any function that is commonly used for this?

Comment: Within what scope do you need these to be unique?  XML just requires them to be unique within the document.  If that's all you need, UUIDs are overkill - just use sequential numbers with a prefix.  They'll be easier to deal with when troubleshooting - it's easier to remember "42" than "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found one - but you could do something like this:

```
public static String generateId() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long randomLong = random.nextLong();
    return ("ID_" + now + "-" + randomLong);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class.

```
String id = "id_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use just some prefix + a sequential number I increment. UUIDs are globally unique, within a document it is rather easy to ensure that `"customprefix"+integer` is unique when you keep the integers unique.